# Change the storage class of an attachment in AWS S3 with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip for attachments and AWS S3 for storage. Paperclip stores attachment as **STANDARD** storage class.

My requirement is to store the attachment initially in **STANDARD** storage class and after some months I want to change the storage class to **GLACIER**. And to retrieve back the attachments in **GLACIER** to **STANDARD** storage class when they requested.

How can I change the storage class of an existing attachment in AWS S3 with Rails? I want to achieve it in code level with ruby instead from AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

So in short; it is not possible to go from Glacier to standard.

> **Amazon S3 supports the following lifecycle transitions between storage classes using a lifecycle configuration:**
>
> You can transition from the STANDARD storage class to any other storage class.
>
> You can transition from any storage class to the GLACIER storage class.
>
> You can transition from the STANDARD_IA storage class to the INTELLIGENT_TIERING or ONEZONE_IA storage classes.
>
> You can transition from the INTELLIGENT_TIERING storage class to the ONEZONE_IA storage class.
>
> **The following lifecycle transitions are not supported:**
>
> You can't transition from any storage class to the STANDARD storage class.
>
> You can't transition from any storage class to the REDUCED_REDUNDANCY storage class.
>
> You can't transition from the INTELLIGENT_TIERING storage class to the STANDARD_IA storage class.
>
> You can't transition from the ONEZONE_IA storage class to the STANDARD_IA or INTELLIGENT_TIERING storage classes.
>
> You can't transition from the GLACIER storage class to any other storage class.

More on the s3 object lifecycles -> [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html)